# loop through array, group results with same date as visually-separated div blocks

Tags: php, loops

I got $users var (2d array). Each array inside $users is like:

```
Name | Username | BirthDay
```

and was filtered as "ORDER BY BirthDay".

I need to output users in format:

```
------ January 15, 2017 -------
Jerry Brown
Angel Keaton
------ January 25, 2017 -------
Kelly Jones
Derrick Wang
Kate Bosch
...
```

meaning that users with same date of birth are grouped in a single "bracket" and separated by date-separator (------ January 15, 2017 -------). Amount of users in each "bracket" may be different each time.

What I can achieve currently outputs:

```
    ------ January 15, 2017 -------
    Jerry Brown
    ------ January 15, 2017 -------
    Angel Keaton
    ------ January 25, 2017 -------
    Kelly Jones
    ------ January 25, 2017 -------
    Derrick Wang
```

or other irrelevant results, which is not quite what's needed. Thanks for any advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a neat way to present your query data in groups like this is to create a grouped data structure as you fetch the rows from the query result. The way you're currently doing it is probably something like this

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = $row;
}
```

which will get you the flat array you currently have.

If you fetch the results into a multidimensional array using the date as a key, then the data will be much more amenable to being displayed in groups like you're trying to do.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[$row['birthday']][] = $row;
}
```

This will get you an array like this instead:

```
$users = [
    'January 15, 2017' => [
        ['name' => 'Jerry Brown', 'birthday' => 'January 15, 2017'],
        ['name' => 'Angel Keaton', 'birthday' => 'January 15, 2017'],
    ],
    'January 25, 2017' => [
        ['name' => 'Kelly Jones', 'birthday' => 'January 25, 2017'],
        ['name' => 'Derrick Wang', 'birthday' => 'January 25, 2017'],
        ['name' => 'Kate Bosch', 'birthday' => 'January 25, 2017'],
    ]
];
```

which you can easily iterate with a nested loop to output in your desired format.

```
foreach ($users as $date => $people) {
    echo "<div>------ $date ------<br>";
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        echo "$person[name]<br>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: thank you - been feeling all the way that this is exactly how it should be done (i.e. reshufle the "flat" array into proper structure first rather then making a loop with bunch of unneeded vars/conditions), but I couldn't accomplish that myself. You made my day - thank you once again! P.S. sorry, cant upvote due to reputation constrains.

Answer (score 0):

Save the last date in a variable and check on the next iteration, if the date changed, close the div and create a new one.

Example, which produces exactly the output you want:

```
$previous = NULL;
$first = true;

echo '<div class="birthday-users">' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($user["birthday"]);
    $headline = date("F d, Y", $timestamp);

    if ($previous !== $headline) {
        if (!$first) {
            echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="birthday-users">' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo '<h1>------ ' . $headline . ' -------</h1>' . PHP_EOL;

        $previous = $headline;

        if ($first) {
            $first = false;
        }
    }

    echo '<p>' . $user["name"] . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</div>';
```